# Responsive Design using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this layout that works well in landscape but does not work at all in portrait. I am trying to adapt the code so that I have an alternative layout in portrait. However I am running into some snags and I cannot help but think that there must be an easier way to do it.

In the code below you can see that when the content (var tent) is longer than the total window (var tots) the normal script runs. However if the content is shorter than the total window the stylesheet is changed and the divs' heights are adjusted to fill the browser's height.

The problem: The code does not update automatically when the browser is resized without being reloaded. Also despite these lines being exactly the same:

```
$('#port_photo').height($('#port_photo').width());
$('#port_video').height($('#port_video').width());
```

The #port_photo dimensions are off and the div is not perfectly squared until the browser is resized.

```
var extras = 12 + 35 + 35;
var tent = $('#port_title').width() * 3 + extras;
var tots = $(window).height();

  $(window).resize(function () {
    if(tent > tots){ 
        $('#port_desc').height( $('#port_desc').width() * 2 - 3 );
        $('#port_video').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1 );
        $('#port_photo').height( $('#port_photo').width() / 2 );
        $('#port_title, .tit').height( $('#port_title').width() / 1 );  
    }else{
        $('link[href="large2.css"]').attr('href','large2_1.css');
        $('#port_photo').height($('#port_photo').width());
        $('#port_video').height($('#port_video').width());
        $('#port_desc').height($(window).height() - $('#port_photo').width() - $('#port_title').height() - 86);
    }
});
```

**If I am not being clear let me know and I will post my website's url.**

Comment: How about CSS media queries instead of, or in addition to, your jQuery?

Comment: Post a question about your attempt with media queries. If your CSS already does what you want and the issue is just switching, it will be easier to just make the query work. (Maybe just change this question if you don't get any answer before editing. If you do get answers to this question as is, post a new question.)

Comment: @Kris, Can you share a demo...

Comment: Yes! @j08691! I did not realize I could target media queries in jquery! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch on giving me a direction to look!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @j08691 for pointing me in the right direction. This the code I ended up going with:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-aspect-ratio: 433/357)" );


if (mq.matches) {
        $('#port_photo').height($('#port_photo').width());
        $('#port_video').height($('#port_video').width());
        $('#port_desc').height($(window).height() - $('#port_photo').width() - $('#port_title').height() - 86);
    } 

if (mq.matches === false) {
        $('#port_desc').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1);
        $('#port_video').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1 );
        $('#port_photo').height( $('#port_photo').width() / 2 );
        $('#port_title, .tit').height( $('#port_title').width() / 1 );  
}

$(window).resize(function () {


    if (mq.matches) {
        $('#port_photo').height($('#port_photo').width());
        $('#port_video').height($('#port_video').width());
        $('#port_desc').height($(window).height() - $('#port_photo').width() - $('#port_title').height() - 86);
    } 

    if (mq.matches === false) {
        $('#port_desc').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1);
        $('#port_video').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1 );
        $('#port_photo').height( $('#port_photo').width() / 2 );
        $('#port_title, .tit').height( $('#port_title').width() / 1 );  
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you only obtain the value of your variables when the page loads, when it resizes those values need to be recalculated. What I mean is:

```
var extras = 12 + 35 + 35;
var tent = $('#port_title').width() * 3 + extras;
var tots = $(window).height();

  $(window).resize(function () {

     tent = $('#port_title').width() * 3 + extras;
     tots = $(window).height();

    if(tent > tots){ 
        $('#port_desc').height( $('#port_desc').width() * 2 - 3 );
        $('#port_video').height( $('#port_video').width() * 1 );
        $('#port_photo').height( $('#port_photo').width() / 2 );
        $('#port_title, .tit').height( $('#port_title').width() / 1 );  
    }else{
        $('link[href="large2.css"]').attr('href','large2_1.css');
        $('#port_photo').height($('#port_photo').width());
        $('#port_video').height($('#port_video').width());
        $('#port_desc').height($(window).height() - $('#port_photo').width() - $('#port_title').height() - 86);
    }
});
```

I hope that this can help you.